# Error : java.sql.SQLException: Exhausted Resultset

Tags: oracle, netbeans

I am trying to give the online test, but this page is not opening when I click on the button to go to test page. 
Here is part of that program :

```
try{
    int i=1;
    Random rand =new Random();
    int newrand=rand.nextInt(9);
    session.setAttribute("aptirandom",String.valueOf(newrand));
    Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
    Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","system","12345");
    String admitid=session.getAttribute("admitid").toString();
    int aid=Integer.parseInt(admitid); 
    PreparedStatement ps1=con.prepareStatement("select aptikey from result where admitid=?");
    ps1.setInt(1,aid);
    ResultSet rs1=ps1.executeQuery();
    rs1.next();
    if(rs1.getInt("aptikey")==1)
                   {
                    response.sendRedirect("AlreadyExam.jsp");
                    }
           else
           {
    PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("select * from aptitude where qid>? order by qid");
    ps.setInt(1,newrand);
    ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();
        while(rs.next() && i<=10)
        {
    %>


    <form action="AptitudeResult.jsp" align="left" name="AptiForm">


        <P><b><%=i%>. <%=rs.getString("question")%></b><BR><BR>  
<input type="radio" name="answer<%=i%>" value="<%=rs.getString("option1")%>"><font color="blue">&nbsp;&nbsp;A.&nbsp;&nbsp;</font><%=rs.getString("option1")%>&nbsp;
```

" value="<%=rs.getString("option2")%>">  B.  <%=rs.getString("option2")%>
" value="<%=rs.getString("option3")%>">  C.  <%=rs.getString("option3")%> 
" value="<%=rs.getString("option4")%>">  C.  <%=rs.getString("option4")%>

```
             <%
                i++;
                     } rs.close();
                        ps.close();        
                        } 
                     con.close();
                     rs1.close();
                     ps1.close();


    }
    catch(NullPointerException e)
                          {
        response.sendRedirect("CandidateLogin.jsp");
    }

            %>

<p><input style="padding-top: 25px; font: 100% arial; border: 1px solid; width: 170px; margin: 0 0 0 212px; height: 33px; padding: 2px 0 3px 0;cursor: pointer;background: #7D0F0F; color: #FFF;"  class="submit" type="submit" name="TestButton" onclick="DoneTest()" value="Submit Aptitude Test"></p>


                    </form>
                    </div>
                           </div>




  <div id="content_footer"></div>

  <div id="footer" >
Copyright © All Rigths Reserved  
  </div>

  </div>
            </body>
                   </html>

Coding of aptituderesult.jsp is below :
```

body>

```
    <div id="main">

    <div id="header">
            <div id="logo">
                 <div id="logo_text">

      <h1>Online Recruitment System</h1>

                </div>
            </div>
    </div>




  <div id="site_content">

  <div id="content">

 <%

try{
    String demo,answer,option;

 Connection con=null;
 String id;
 int aptimarks=0;
 int qid;
 int total=0;
 int i=1;
  String random=session.getAttribute("aptirandom").toString();
 try{

  Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
  con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","system","12345");
           }
 catch(Exception e)
                     {
     e.printStackTrace();
   }

    PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("select * from aptitude where qid>? order by qid");
    ps.setString(1,random); 
    ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();
    while(rs.next()){
        answer=rs.getString("answer");
        qid=rs.getInt("qid");
        id=String.valueOf(i);
        demo="answer".concat(id);
        option=request.getParameter(demo);
        if(answer.equals(option))
        {
            aptimarks++;
        }
        i++;
    }


    String admitid=session.getAttribute("admitid").toString();
    int aid=Integer.parseInt(admitid); 


    PreparedStatement ps1=con.prepareStatement("select total from result where admitid=?");
    ps1.setInt(1,aid);
    ResultSet rs1=ps1.executeQuery();
    rs1.next();
    total=rs1.getInt("total");
    total=total+aptimarks;


    PreparedStatement ps2=con.prepareStatement("update result set aptiresult=?,aptikey=1,total=? where admitid=?");
    ps2.setInt(1,aptimarks);
    ps2.setInt(2,total);
    ps2.setInt(3,aid);
    ps2.executeUpdate();



    response.sendRedirect("TestHome.jsp");

        }
catch(NullPointerException e)
           {
    response.sendRedirect("TestHome.jsp");
}
```

%>

```
                </div>
                           </div>




  <div id="content_footer"></div>

  <div id="footer" >
  Copyright : Inderjeet Singh |Designed in JSP | JAVA | Struts |
  </div>

  </div>
            </body>
                   </html>
```

Comment: Is there always a record to select from `result`? If not the `rs1.next()` would get false, and the following `rs1.getInt()` might throw that exception. Also, are you really meaning to start a new `<form>` for each of the 10 questions you pick? I'm unclear quite what you're seeing and when...

Comment: Yes there is a record to select from result. I had entered 2 questions yet, and their answers.  Yes, this page must open a new form.

Comment: But you're generating the <form> tag inside the loop, so you'll get 10 *nested* forms, won't you? Which doesn't sound right. But that isn't related to an SQL error. If you have a matching record in `result` then not sure where that comes from, unless it's in later code you haven't shown.

Comment: Let me try entring 10 questions in sql.

Comment: I entered 10 questions, I am again getting same error.

Comment: Later part of coding is this :

Comment: <P><b><%=i%>. <%=rs.getString("question")%></b><BR><BR>
<input type="radio" name="answer<%=i%>" value="<%=rs.getString("option1")%>"><font color="blue">&nbsp;&nbsp;A.&nbsp;&nbsp;</font><%=rs.getString("option1")%>&nbsp;
<input type="radio" name="answer<%=i%>" value="<%=rs.getString("option2")%>"><font color="blue">&nbsp;&nbsp;B.&nbsp;&nbsp;</font><%=rs.getString("option2")%><br><br>
<input type="radio" name="answer<%=i%>" value="<%=rs.getString("option3")%>"><font color="blue">&nbsp;&nbsp;C.&nbsp;&nbsp;</font><%=rs.getString("option3")%>&nbsp;

Comment: Seriously, it didn't occur to you while pasting that across multiple comments that it should be added as an edit to the question instead? You need to decide if you're asking about the exhausted result error, the page not displaying, or the invalid login error. I hope you're not really connecting/working as `SYSTEM`, and that isn't the real pasword for that account...

Comment: exhausted result is the error. There was a logon error, but I wrote right username and password, so that was removed.

Comment: Still the only problem I can see is if there is no `result` record for your `admitid`. Does the problem go away if you change that to `if(rs1.next() && rs1.getInt("aptikey")==1)` instead of having two statements and not checking the result of the `next()`? Also you're closing `rs1` and `ps1` after `con`, but that shouldn't error I think. If that doesn't help you need to add debugs to see which statement is throwing the error, or look at the stack trace.

Comment: This page had worked, but when I clicked on 'Submit' Button after giving answers, I get error : java.sql.SQLException: Exhausted Resultset

Comment: Only half problem solved. I clicked on test button. Test opened, I gave answers and clicked 'Submit'. I got message, Test Submitted Successfully. After that I get error message : - java.sql.SQLException: Exhausted Resultset 

Here is code of program : - 
function DoneTest() 
{ 
alert("Test Submitted Successfully"); 
} 
function newfunc() 
{ 

VerbForm.submit(); 
} 

window.onbeforeunload=newfunc; 
</script> 


<SCRIPT type="text/javascript"> 
window.history.forward(); 
function noBack() { window.history.forward(); }

Comment: Please **stop** posting code in the comments. When you submit the page generated by the code above, it goes to `AptitudeReslt.jsp`, which is a different page, right? And it's that page, not the one above, that throws the error? Please update the question with all the information in a coherent order, you're making it impossible to help you.

Comment: First error was in first program, it was soloved. So one step of program ran. Now error is happening after clicking Submit button. Error message is same. I had posted coding of both programs in question now.

Answer (score 0):

keep your rs1.next() inside if condition bcz u can't call rs1.getInt("") method directly.

Comment: I get message, 'Test Submitted Successfully', after giving the test, and on clicking the 'Submit' Button. After that error is same.